# Share artifacts between two packaged Analytics templates

Tags: einstein-analytics, template, crm-analytics

My Managed Package should contain two Wave/TCRM/Analytics templates:

- **FULL:** Type `app` for subscribers with a Full Analytics Studio license
- **EMBEDDED:** Type `embeddedapp` for subscribers with NO such license

I want the EMBEDDED template to use the same datasets and dashboards as the FULL template so I don't need to maintain redundant, duplicated TCRM artifacts.

**Failed Approach: Template Dependencies**

I planned to do this using [**Template Dependencies**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_wave_templates.meta/bi_dev_guide_wave_templates/bi_templatesdev_share_assets.htm), but I just stumbled over this and wonder if my whole goal is not feasible. I also found no working sample of dependent templates on GitHub and found the documentation to be of little help.

[image]

**Failed Approach: One App - Two templates**
Would it work to create two different templates from one Source App and then update both templates when the app changes?

According to [Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/de/content/learn/modules/wave_analytics_templates_intro/wave_analytics_templates_in_action) it is not possible:

> As shown here, you can create one template from each source app.
> Others can then use the template to create multiple instances of the
> app.

**How can I solve this obvious scenario then?**

Answer (score 1):

Robert,
Can you please help us understand what is the purpose of the two templates? You could potentially, create 1 template with all the source datasets and dashboards in an embedded template. Full users will be able to see all the assets even if it is an embedded type template.

If full template has more assets, you could make it the dependent template, have the embedded template auto-install, then have full users install the full template app from studio.
@khotchkiss, thoughts?

Comment: I assumed that I need 2 templates to provide both a Free (no Analytics license) and a Full (with Analytics Studio Licence) version of my dashboards and artifacts. 
Is this not the case. Can I put ALL artifacts in a type=embeddedapp template and make it usable with a wizard for Full users and via a LWC for the Free users?